# Not able to connect to websocket using Nginx and Uvicorn

Tags: django, docker, nginx, websocket, uvicorn

I built a docker container with Django, Uvicorn, Nginx and Redis, and am using django-channels but when I run this it says it cannot connect to the websocket and this is seen in the browser console:

> `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/ws/notifications/' failed`

It is working fine when I use Django's runserver command for development but when I include Nginx and Uvicorn it breaks.

Entrypoint.sh:

```
gunicorn roomway.asgi:application --forwarded-allow-ips='*' --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

Nginx config:

```
upstream django {
    server app:8000;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS={
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('redis', 6379)],  #Redis port
        }
    }
}
```

The JS file which handles the socket:

```
var wsStart = "ws://"    
var webSocketEndpoint =  wsStart + window.location.host + '/ws/notifications/'
const notificationSocket = new WebSocket(webSocketEndpoint)
```

asgi.py:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            url(r'^ws/notifications/', NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
            path("ws/<str:room_name>/", ChatConsumer.as_asgi())            
        ])
    )
})
```

Nginx throws this error with the above code:

```
[error] 23#23: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, server: , request: "GET /ws/notifications/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:8000/ws/notifications/", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
```

When I change the `proxy_pass` to `http://django` instead of `0.0.0.0`, Nginx does not throw that error anymore but I get the same error on the console. Also this time Django throws these warnings:

```
[WARNING] Unsupported upgrade request.       
[WARNING] No supported WebSocket library detected. Please use 'pip install uvicorn[standard]', or install 'websockets' or 'wsproto' manually.
```

Comment: Do you need to change proxy_pass to  send the request to your django container `proxy_pass http://django;`? Currently you're just passing it to "0.0.0.0"

Comment: @lian I tried that right now but am still getting the same error on the console. Though this time, I get a warning from the Django app which says:
[WARNING] Unsupported upgrade request.
[WARNING] No supported WebSocket library detected. Please use 'pip install uvicorn[standard]', or install 'websockets' or 'wsproto' manually.

Which is strange considering I have django-channels installed

Comment: channels will not install uvicorn for you, if you want to run gunicorn/uvcorn you will need to install it

Comment: I have already have gunicorn==20.1.0 and uvicorn==0.15.0 installed on the container

Comment: Try installing `uvicorn[standard]` instead:`pip uninstall uvicorn && pip install uvicorn[standard]`. It seems websocket support may not be included in the base install

Comment: Yes that was it!! Thanks man. I also moved Twisted to version 20.3 because of some compatibilty issues.

Comment: installing ```uvicorn[standard``` did iit for me. Thanks man, @IainShelvington

Comment: @IainShelvington I wish I could see your answer earlier, it could save nearly a week of efforts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As noted in a comment by [Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington), it seems like websockets are not included in the base install of uvicorn

```bash
pip uninstall uvicorn
pip install 'uvicorn[standard]'
```

Comment: On some shells it may complain that the package cannot be found. You have to quote the package: `pip install 'uvicorn[standard]'`

Answer (score 2):

```
pip uninstall uvicorn
pip install "uvicorn[standard]"
```

Use **Double Quotation**

Answer (score 0):

If you use `"uvicorn[standart]"` maybe cannot see `websocket` 
if occures error like that: install websocket `pip install websocket`